# How to remove rows with values that include " signs

Tags: sql-server

I would like to filter out rows that contain the word: `Artist`. I tried to use the following statement but it doesn't work, I think it's because of the `"` signs.How can I remove those rows ?

```
IdUser  FirstName   LastName    usrLogin    AllProfiles AllGeners
111         Car      Cal          fff       "Artist,"     "Artist,"
```

The statement that I used:

```
where (AllProfiles <> 'Artist'  OR AllGeners <> 'Artist,' )
```

An update:
How can remove rows where the values is "Artist," but not remove rows with values : "Artist,Collector"

Comment: `WHERE AllProfiles NOT Like '%Artist%' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for a String and it needs to match EXACTLY for it to return true.  You are not including the double quotation marks round the word artist.

As mentioned by a few others you could use a LIKE statement add % to allow for other characters before or after your search term

```
where (AllProfiles NOT LIKE '%Artist%')
```

Or if you do not want to slow your search down then explicitly search for the terms you mean and include the double quotes

```
where (AllProfiles <> '"Artist"' OR AllGeners <> '"Artist,"' )
```

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
where (AllProfiles <> '"Artist"'  OR AllGeners <> '"Artist,"' )
or 
where (AllProfiles not like '%Artist'  OR AllGeners not like '%Artist,' )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use REPLACE:

```
where (REPLACE(AllProfiles,'"','') <> 'Artist'  OR REPLACE(AllGeners,'"','') <> 'Artist,' )
```

Or LIKE:

```
where (AllProfiles NOT LIKE '%Artist%' OR AllGeners NOT LIKE '%Artist%')
```

Or you can UPDATE table to replace `"`:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET AllProfiles = REPLACE(AllProfiles,'"',''), AllGeners = REPLACE(AllGeners,'"','')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter **all rows containing the word *Artist***, then you should use the NOT LIKE operator.

```
... WHERE AllGeners NOT LIKE '%Artist%' OR AllProfiles NOT LIKE '%Artist%'
```